# What's the exact difference between Keys.Control/Shift and Keys.ControlKey/ShiftKey?

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard, key

What's the exact difference between Keys.Control and Keys.ControlKey/Keys.Shift and Keys.ShiftKey in System.Windows.Forms?

I've googled it but nothing specific came up, and it doesn't seem to be documented on MSDN either.

Personally, I always use Keys.Control/Keys.Shift, because it works fine.

---

Edit: After reading KreepN's answer, I thought if you never have to use Control/Shift, why are they in the framework?

I mean, they aren't even the physical keys, so I can't see the reason why Microsoft decided to create them.

Are there circumstances where it's better to use Control/Shift?

Comment: You use Keys.Control to check if the user is holding the Ctrl key down.  To detect Ctrl+C for example.  You use Keys.ControlKey to detect the user pressing the Ctrl key.  Which is unusual unless you write a game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ControlKey and ShiftKey (and Menu--which you would assume would have been
named AltKey) represent the physical keys themselves. In other words, they
are "actual" keys and can be found in the KeyCode property of a KeyEventArgs
object.

Control, Shift, and Alt, on the other hand, will never appear in the KeyCode
property, but their values can be found in the KeyData property. It seems
you never actually NEED to use these constants, because the framework
already pulls them out for you via the Alt, Control, and Shift properties of
the KeyEventArgs object, but you CAN use them to test against the KeyData
property if you really want to.

[Source with Examples](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/2008-04/msg00127.html).

Edit for your edit:

Look at the values that are returned when the "a" key is pressed:

a (unshifted) / 41 / 41

A (Shift+a) / 41 / 10041

Ctrl+a / 41 / 20041

The "KeyCode" in this case is = 41 for all modifiers. You could use this in code if all you cared about was the primary button pressed, in this case "a".

If you wanted to have different functionality based on if a modifier was pressed you would need to get more specific and reference the "KeyData" field and look for the # that denoted a certain modifier. In this case "100" for shift and "200" for control at the beginning of the field.

That's not to say you couldn't just check for the "41" at the end of the KeyData field, but I've never been one to complain about convenience.

It would be safe to say that the "difference" you are looking for between them in your first question is that they reference different property fields.

Edit for additional relevance:
The key modifier values combined with the key value directly correlate to the Shortcut enumeration members. For example:
Shortcut.CtrlF8 ( 0x20077 ) is the same as Keys.Control | Keys.F8 ( 0x20000 | 0x77 )

This can be useful when dealing with the defined Shortcut properties of menu items.

Comment: Great answer -> Accepted, but added a part to the question and will be accepting an answer that answers both my questions.

Comment: Clarified and explained, sorry bout that.